# Parsing hyperlinks from Access VBA to Word template

Tags: ms-access, hyperlink, ms-word, vba

I'm using VBA in Access 2010 form to populate a Word template with data from my tables.

What I can't achieve so far is inserting a hyperlink in the text.

To make things easier for me I'm inserting all the data into table in the template like this:

```
Private Sub button_Click()

On Error GoTo myError
Dim objWRD As Object 'Word.Application
Dim objDoc As Object 'Word.Document
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strRecords As String

'open a query and prepare the data'
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set qfd = db.QueryDefs("my_query")
Set rs = qfd.OpenRecordset()

'open a Word template'
Set objWRD = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWRD.Visible = True
Set objDoc = objWRD.Documents.Add("path_to_my_document_template", , , True)
objWRD.ScreenUpdating = False


'insert records into template'
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
While Not rs.EOF
    objDoc.Tables(i).Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = "" & rs("hyperlink")
    objDoc.Tables(i).Cell(2, 2).Range.Text = "" & rs("description")
    rs.MoveNext
    i = i + 1
Wend

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

leave:
    Exit Sub
myError:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

Can anyone please help me to insert a working hyperlink to the template into     `rs("hyperlink")` place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you reference the table cell to hold the hyperlink, try this:

```
objDoc.Hyperlinks.add Anchor:=objDoc.tables(i).Cell(2, 1).Range, _
    Address:=rs("hyperlink")
```

And to add additional text to the same cell (In this case I'm inserting "Text to Insert" prior to the hyperlink.

```
With objDoc.Tables(i).Cell(2, 1).Range
    .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
    .Text = "Text to Insert" & Chr(11)
End With
```

so your While Loop would look something like this:

```
 Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    While Not rs.EOF

    objDoc.Hyperlinks.add Anchor:=objDoc.Tables(i).Cell(2, 1).Range, _
        Address:=rs("hyperlink")
    With objDoc.Tables(i).Cell(2, 1).Range
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
        .Text = "Text to Insert" & Chr(11)
    End With
   objDoc.Tables(i).Cell(2, 2).Range.Text = "" & rs("description")
        rs.MoveNext
        i = i + 1
    Wend
```

Comment: Thanks, RyanL, this is actually working pretty well for the whole cell in a table. I can also use a `TextToDisplay` parameter to change the text of a link. But what if I need to add more text to the same table cell? So I need to have some text and a hyperlink in the same cell. Is this possible?